# Code to compare the number of "false" to total number of cases

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to create a chart in tableau which will show me the comparison in weeks, i.e. the comparison between the trend from week 1 to week 5.

In simple terms it should be like:

```
If Verdict = "Not Reversing" THEN count the total number of Verdicts
```

Else do not count

```
If IF [Verdict] = "Not Reversing" 
THEN
COUNT([Verdict])

END

IF [Verdict] = "Not Reversing" 
THEN
COUNT([Verdict])

END
```

> Error message shows cannot mix aggregate and non aggregate functions

Comment: Count() does not do what you seem think it does. Count([My Field]) returns the number of records that have a (non-null) value in the [My Field] column

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data source has exactly one data row per verdict ... (Always be clear about what one row in your data source represents.)

You could define a calculated field called **Number of Non Reversing Verdicts** defined as `INT([Verdict] = "Non Reversing")` That field will have the value 1 for Non Reversing verdicts and 0 otherwise. The INT() function converts its arguments into an integer, and treats TRUE as 1 and FALSE as 0.

You can then plot SUM([Number of Non Reversing Verdicts]) as desired, along with SUM([Number of Records]) to see the total number of verdicts -- or even compute the ratio of the two formatted as a percentage.

For extra credit, you could rename the predefined field [Number of Records] to [Number of Verdicts] for this data source if that helps make it more clear. (BTW, look at the definition of [Number of Records] and make sure you understand why that works)